# flutter appbar is disappeared

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, navigator

my appbar is disappeared when i go new page using navigator
actually, there was a yellow underline on the new page's text.
I found that's reason is the page didn't have Material.
so i added the Material Widget on that, so I could fixed the problem of text underline.
i think appbar disappeared problem also relates with Material,
but even i wrapped the code with Material widget, still the problem is not solved.
what can i do?

here is the navigator code.
exhibition[i] is what i wanted to transmit to new page(=DetailScreen)

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () {Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>DetailScreen(exhibition: exhibitions[i])),
        );
```

And the below is DetailScreen(new page)'s code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'model_exhibitions.dart';

class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Exhibition exhibition;

  DetailScreen({required this.exhibition});

  State<DetailScreen> createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  bool bookmark = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bookmark = widget.exhibition.bookmark;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 0, 0),
        child: Row( ...
```

Thank you for your help sincerely

Comment: You have to add an app bar in material -> scaffold widget

Comment: thank you, but in others pages, appbar was generated automatically, do you know why this is not acting that?

Comment: I don't quite believe you that "appbar was generated automatically". Typically a new "page" widget is a Scaffold (as the parent) then the appbar can be added to the scaffold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'model_exhibitions.dart';

class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Exhibition exhibition;

  DetailScreen({required this.exhibition});

  State<DetailScreen> createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  bool bookmark = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bookmark = widget.exhibition.bookmark;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(   //add scaffold

       body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 0, 0),
        child: Row( ...
```

> It will not work without scaffold.
>
> I think you are not getting what scaffold is and how it's behaviour
> is?
>
> Scaffold is a widget which provides your screen/route a default
> behaviour similar to your android/ios screens like AppBar, Body,
> Title, FloatingActionButton, Drawer etc.
>
> So that you do not have to make yourself a new structure.
>
> If you are not using scaffold, then your page will act like a plain
> body structure in which you have to fill custom widgets as per your
> requirements.

Comment: youre right, i think i nee to learn again from structure of flutter, thank you!